# Facing Issue in Creating/Setting up React Native Project on System

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, react-native, enoent

Below are the errors which I am facing. Any help would be really appreciated. If anything else needed from my side please let me know.

```
C:\Users\manikthakur\Desktop>create-react-native-app MyReactNative
This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]? Y
Installing the package 'expo-cli'...
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Windows\System32 ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\manikthakur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\create-react-native-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:29)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it worked now for me. Below is the solution which worked for the above issue.

Your ComSpec environment variable is wrong, replace:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Windows\System32
```

With the following:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
```

Then restart your **cmd** and retry to generate a project.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, windows is a little scared when it comes to desktop access `C:\Users\<user>\Desktop`.

Given that it is an error on an async tick, maybe it is filed access related, Try to create a new folder somewhere that is not restricted (maybe documents, or `c:\tmp`) then run the command from there

1. WinKey + R
2. Type `cmd`
3. List item
4. run command `cd c:\`
5. run command `mkdir tmp`
6. run command `cd tmp`
7. run your existing command `create-react-native-app MyReactNative`

Comment: I might need more details to understand the issues here, how did you get to this point >]?

Comment: I am following https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_environment_setup.htm to setup reactNative on my system. Anything else needed please let  me know.

Comment: Seems like you might have missed one of the global modules to be installed 

> [ npm install *-g* create-react-native-app expo-cli ]
then 
> [ create-react-native-app MyReactNative ]